# Watching http in wireshark

Tags: http, wireshark

Wireshark reassembles TCP Segments. For teaching purposes, I'd like to see the actual packets (not the reassembled TCP Segments) that flow on a network when you access a webpage.

Can I do that with Wireshark? If not, can you suggest a free program that will let me see the basic, fundamental packets?

Answer (score 2):

You should disable `TCP Reassembly` and `IP Reassembly` in `Wireshark`. These features change packet bytes. For example `IP Reassembly` shows IP and TCP headers in the last packet of datagram where as they are in the first packet.

To disable these features:

1. Select one packet in `Wireshark`
2. Select its `IP Header`and Right Click on it
3. Unckeck **Reassemble Fragmented IPv4 datagrams** under *Protocol Preferences*
4. Select packet's `TCP Header` and Right Click on it
5. Uncked **Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams** under *Protocol Preferences*

This changes are saved automatically and are valid in other running of `Wireshark`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view only `http packets` in wireshark

- Start the wireshark
- Select your network adaptor
- In Filter box enter 'http' and then apply.

Comment: What if wireshark doesn't show any HTTP packets, just TCP, UDP, ARP and others?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol) can help you filter out non-HTTP traffic. Then you can simply [look](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChapterWork.html) at the packets:

> 6.1. Viewing packets you have captured
>
> Once you have captured some packets, or you have opened a previously
>   saved capture file, you can view the packets that are displayed in the
>   packet list pane by simply clicking on a packet in the packet list
>   pane, which will bring up the selected packet in the tree view and
>   byte view panes.

You can also disable packet reassembling as shown [here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvReassemblySection.html). [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) may also be a good choice if you want to look at HTTP layer.