# Closed network - "fake" an active internet connection?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a closed wifi network (so no WAN/Internet access) for an event - with a private website.

While I got everything working fine, I'm wondering if I can solve the long loading time for the wifi clients to connect - while they are trying to find an active internet connection.

- On an iPad, it just takes a long time - no warning. But it connects fine.
- On a Windows computer, it starts to load - then displays "connecting
  to network is taking longer than usual" - and then it connects and
  shows "limited". I'm using DNSMasq on a Raspberry Pi 3 to hand out IP
  addresses (works perfectly), and have dns configured so that I can
  use local domain names (domain.dev - works fine).

**So I was wondering what I can do to get rid of that time-delay and warning message? Any pointers?**

Comment: «while they are trying to find an active internet connection» Are you sure this is not precisely the cause? iOS and Windows may decide to estabilish their own timeout (e.g. in seconds) for this test. In this case, there is not much you can do about it. Have you tried to sniff with Wireshark to see exactly what they are trying to do?

Comment: I'm not that versed in packet sniffing. I was wondering if there wasn't a solution that would capture all internet-related traffic and just return valid 200 codes - faking an active internet connection. Or something like that.

Comment: And to answer your question: yes, I'm pretty sure that's exactly the cause. I'm looking for a way to circumvent that.

Comment: Taapo, that would require tweaking your DNS server and having a basic HTTP server running on your Raspberry-turned-router. Yes, it is possible. :) But before saying "this is an answer", I would suggest you run Wireshark and sniff a bit. You just need to [watch the HTTP traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/327955/watching-http-in-wireshark).

Comment: I've normally seen it after a sleep/hibernate/restart, and it seems to take some time for network connections (especially wireless) to re-establish themselves after the network card has been put into low/no power mode. It may help to keep the network card alive in sleep mode and to put some background network accesses into the start up/end hibernate processes.

Comment: @AFH That won't work for iPads though.

Comment: I guess not, and in any case iPads already keep the network active while sleeping, though I've never known why they have so much better battery life than sleeping Androids, where a lot of the power goes on WiFi. Maybe the network sleeps most of the time, but it's brought up for occasional checks.

Comment: @AFH - it's actually the complete opposite. I haven't found a way to keep the wifi connected to Wifi on an iPad while in sleep mode. Apple apparently - as they always do - removed the feature and now it disconnects from Wifi when you turn off the screen. When you turn on the screen again, it takes 50 seconds to connect to my network again. There must be a way to have it connect much faster again.

Comment: I hadn't realised: my iPad always used to accumulate notifications while dormant, but now you mention it I haven't noticed them recently, and I have started keeping up with the latest iOS revisions since I managed to free enough disc space to do this.